# Android - Connecting to MS Sharepoint via CSOM or REST causes local file system UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, android, sharepoint, permissions, csom

I'm developing an app in C# (via Unity) for Android devices that links to Microsoft's SharePoint system for files and information.
C# applications can connect to SharePoint via the CSOM api or REST api. This works in test and on Windows.

Everything is working successfully apart from one critical part:

When running on an actual Android tablet (Samsung Tab 8 - Android 10) it returns error:

```
Error Unity UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/assets" is denied.
```

This happens when the CSOM  `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()`; function runs.

So I tried using REST method instead. But this returns the same AccessExeption at:

```
data = client.DownloadData(endpointUri);
```

These commands are essential for both method for retrieving information. I can only imagine it is storing some kind of temporary info, as it doesn't actually need to save anything here at this point, just download info into a temporary variable. The actual writing to a file location comes later.

I have also tested 'Directory("/test")' and this returns the same AccessExeption.
Everything else on the app writes to the Application.PersistentDataPath etc and works fine.

Is there a way to make this part of Android Internal filesystem accessible?
I have done the  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  and  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the Manifest.
They are requested and granted when I run the App and all other read writing works fine to other location (like photos, Android/Data/App name/Files etc).

I can create a test image file and save it using this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath +  Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Local saves" + separator + "image.jpg", bytes);
```

This image file and folder appear on the Android device (i've done this sort of stuff loads of times), so it can definitely write to the Application.persistentDataPath

Directory.CreateDirectory,   Directory.CreateFile,  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes
all work fine to the Application.persistentDataPath.

For some reason something in the REST code and/or CSOM's executeQuery() are trying to access elsewhere, but they don't request a filepath, so how can I make them work?

Any advise much appreciated, I have been spending the most part of several days trying to work this out and nothing is working.

The REST code to download a file in test and downloads file on windows.
(the last few lines are commented out to pin down which bit was throwing the error)

```
    public static void DownloadFileViaRestAPI(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string documentLibName, string fileName, string path)
    {
        webUrl = webUrl.EndsWith("/") ? webUrl.Substring(0, webUrl.Length - 1) : webUrl;
        string webRelativeUrl = null;
        if (webUrl.Split('/').Length > 3)
        {
            webRelativeUrl = "/" + webUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, 4)[3];
        }
        else
        {
            webRelativeUrl = "";
        }
        
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            Uri endpointUri = new Uri(webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + webRelativeUrl + "/" + documentLibName + "/" + fileName + "')/$value");
            //string result = client.DownloadString(endpointUri);
            byte[] data = client.DownloadData(endpointUri);
            //char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            
            //FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(SharedData.appRoot + "Local saves" + separator + fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            //outputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            //outputStream.Flush(true);
            //outputStream.Close();
        }
        
    }
```

The error at `byte[] data = client.DownloadData(endpointUri);`
:

```
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/assets" is denied.
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x0004b] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00094] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create()
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00023] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00094] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create()
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00023] in <2b3a3162be434770b7a4fac8b896e90c>:0 
2021/03/15 15:54:10.428 8826 8881 Error Unity   at System.IO.Directory.Crea
```

In some ways this makes sense. Both CSOM or REST will be creating some kind of temporary space as download the file. But how would change where this is or allow them access?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is some guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint) about what API is appropriate for different device types.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying so quickly. 
REST api came up in my research other day so your link confirms this appears to be best option instead of CSOM.
Just annoying MS's other help page on CSOM says it is for IOS and Android apps too :) - I will try this and report back

Comment: I've edited original post

Comment: Still no further along. Absolutely nothing I try works. Spent another solid 4 hours on this today alone testing things.
Using REST, as soon as it runs client.DownloadData or client.DownloadFile its doesnt do anything. the error mentions it is trying to access "/assets", but I'm not asking it to and can't find how to give it permission anyway.

Comment: I don't do android development, but I use the MS Graph API to interact with sharepoint. If you can write http requests, you should be able to use the [Graph API.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: Thank you I will take a look. 
My experience is mainly in C# and java, not http Get requests.
My main aim to to have a reliable way to download a file, upload a file and ideally get a list of files/directories.

Comment: I do all those things with graph api. There may be a client sdk for .net that makes it easier, but at the time i created my library those sdks were in preview so I have to do a lot of the work myself but it works.

Comment: I think I'm at the edge of giving up on this and calling it a day.  I tried the graph root, but can't work out how to get an Auth Token, my knowledge and understanding of it is Zero.
I downloaded the Postman utility and followed a long tutorial of how to get an access token (this is just so i can test if the issue was something to do with  modern credentials) but i'm not getting the response back through Postman i apparently should. So that's 4 hours gone on that dead end. :/